# ExtJS panel not rendering with JsonStore and local Json file

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

I'm trying to display information in a panel from a local json file (for testing purposes). This is being done in firefox and I am not running this on a server. I thought this would be possible without doing that.

```
Ext.define('APL.view.result.List' ,{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
alias: 'widget.resultlist',

title: 'All Users',

initComponent: function() {
    this.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'sample_2.json',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'features',
                record: 'properties'
            }
        },
        //alternatively, a Ext.data.Model name can be given (see Ext.data.Store for an example)
        fields: ['prop0']
    });

    this.columns = [
        {header: 'Property',  dataIndex: 'prop0',  flex: 1},
    ];

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

I create and launch the panel from another file

```
Ext.application({
requires: ['Ext.container.Viewport'],
name: 'APL',

appFolder: 'app',

controllers: [
    'Results'
],

launch: function() {
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'resultlist'
            }
        ]
    });
}
});
```

When run as shown, the table is empty. No logs or any record of requests being sent in the networks tab.

I tried using these two resources when making this: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?215035-Reading-and-displaying-data-in-extjs-from-a-Json-file and http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/guide/application_architecture

And here is the JSON file I am trying to use:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
  { "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
    "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    },
  { "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "LineString",
      "coordinates": [
        [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
        ]
      },
    "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
    },
  { "type": "Feature",
     "geometry": {
       "type": "Polygon",
       "coordinates": [
         [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0],
           [100.0, 1.0], [100.0, 0.0] ]
         ]
     },
     "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
     }
   ]
 }
```

Comment: You need to run it through a server. Also, you need to load the store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running it via file:// protocol it is not going to work because Ajax can work only via http:// or https:// protocols. Install a http server locally, it is not that difficult.

Here are [video instructions](http://extjs.eu/videos) how to prepare your computer for Ext JS development.

Comment: I thought there was some way to read in Json files locally. Maybe not using ajax, but is there some other way it could be done?

Comment: Unfortunately, no way, mainly for security reasons.